# Laravel : how to return route name inside web.php file

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have web app by Laravel ,I want to make routing depend on login status inside web.php file for a reason.
i make this :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if (!Auth::guest()){
        return ???????
    }
    
else {
    return view('welcome');
}
```

I want to return route named "home" , How can I do that ?

Comment: i think you need to use `middleware for this sinario

Comment: You better have a auth middleware?

Comment: can I do it without middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I using middleware for all my routes if need ,but for a reason I need to do this ,I did this and solved ,this if I don't have argument to pass:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if (!Auth::guest()){
        return view('home');
    }
    
else {
    return view('welcome');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the routes exists, then this should work.

```
Route::get('/', function() {
   return (!Auth::guest()) view('home') : view("welcome");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'is_admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('home');
    });
});
```